# Why can't I upgrade chocolatey by using the command line "choco upgrade chocolatey"?

Tags: upgrade, chocolatey, choco

I tried to run this command line in Powershell in administrator mode:

```
choco upgrade chocolatey
```

But it returned:

```
Chocolatey v1.1.0
Upgrading the following packages:
chocolatey
By upgrading, you accept licenses for the packages.
chocolatey v1.1.0 is the latest version available based on your source(s).

Chocolatey upgraded 0/1 packages.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
```

And `upgraded 0/1 packages` means it upgraded failed.

When I check the log for further reasons, it says:

```
2022-08-19 03:18:28,329 19084 [DEBUG] - _ Chocolatey:ChocolateyUpgradeCommand - Normal Run Mode _
2022-08-19 03:18:28,332 19084 [INFO ] - Upgrading the following packages:
2022-08-19 03:18:28,332 19084 [INFO ] - chocolatey
2022-08-19 03:18:28,332 19084 [INFO ] - By upgrading, you accept licenses for the packages.
2022-08-19 03:18:28,425 19084 [DEBUG] - Using 'https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'.
2022-08-19 03:18:29,753 19084 [DEBUG] - - Supports prereleases? 'True'.
2022-08-19 03:18:29,763 19084 [DEBUG] - - Is ServiceBased? 'True'.
2022-08-19 03:18:30,331 19084 [DEBUG] - Package 'chocolatey' found on source 'https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
2022-08-19 03:18:30,335 19084 [INFO ] - chocolatey v1.1.0 is the latest version available based on your source(s).
2022-08-19 03:18:30,343 19084 [WARN ] - 
Chocolatey upgraded 0/1 packages. 
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
2022-08-19 03:18:30,350 19084 [WARN ] - 
Enjoy using Chocolatey? Explore more amazing features to take your
experience to the next level at
 https://chocolatey.org/compare
2022-08-19 03:18:30,352 19084 [DEBUG] - Sending message 'PostRunMessage' out if there are subscribers...
2022-08-19 03:18:30,355 19084 [DEBUG] - Exiting with 0
```

Comment: Did you read the error? "chocolatey v1.1.0 is the latest version available based on your source(s)" You can't update if there's no update

Comment: @Samathingamajig That's sure, the latest version is 1.0.0 by now. Sorry I'm not a native English speaker, and it's really a bit awkward to ask a question like this... But anyway, thanks a lot for your reply!

Comment: @GaryEwanPark Yes, that's exactly what I encountered, thanks for your reply!